# Facing issues while using cancan gem in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cancan

Hi I am using cancan gem for the first time. I have included this in my gem file

```
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
```

then done bundle install and run command **rails g cancan:ability** through which my ability.rb is generated in which I have given this code

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(employee)
    employee ||= Employee.new
    if employee[:role]== 'HR'
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

and in my application_Controller given this

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to root_url
 end
```

Now I have sign in with employee[:role]= 'HR' and when I am going to create departments then it gives me error

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<DepartmentsController:0xb48a0c0>):
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:357:in `current_ability'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:215:in `current_ability'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:98:in `initial_attributes'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:91:in `assign_attributes'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:86:in `build_resource'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:66:in `load_resource_instance'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
```

[image]

Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have Devise for User or Employee? also post your devise routes

Comment: No am using authlogic

Comment: you must be having current_user helper method defined in application_controller. right?

Comment: do you have following in your application controller e.g.

`helper_method :current_user

private
def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end`

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the current_ability method in application_controller.rb

```
def current_ability
   @current_ability ||= Ability.new(your_current_logged_in_employer_object)
end
```